# mongoose Querying inner document array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a schema design like this

```
var userNotificationSchema = new Schema({
    notification_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'notifications' },
    isRead: { type: Boolean }   
});

var userSchema = new Schema({
    notification: [userNotificationSchema]
});
```

I want to fetch all notifications array list which `isRead: 'false'`.

For that I wrote

```
Model.User.find({
    _id: userid,
    'notification.isRead': false 
}, function (err, result) { 
    console.log(result);
    res.send(result);
});
```

but this returns `[]` as result.

Comment: what is your mongoose version used in the app?

Comment: mongoose version 4.6.1

Comment: query looks correct, is userid is correct for _id?

Comment: Have you tried querying with just the `isRead` property, as in `Model.User.find({ "notification.isRead": false }).exec(callback)`? Do you get any results? If so, then check if the query with just the `userid` works, i.e. `Model.User.find({ "_id": userid }).exec(callback)`. If that doesn't give you any result then it means the `userid` you specified does not exist and that potentially could be the reason why the combined filter is not working.

Answer (score 1):

you can try it using `aggregate` if you want to get only those notifications that has `isRead` field is `false`.

```
Model.User.aggregate([
  {$match:{_id: userid}},
  {$unwind:"$notification"},
  {$match:{"notification.isRead": false}},
  {$group:{_id:"$_id",notification:{ $addToSet: "$notification"}}}
]).exec(function (err, result) {
  console.log(result);
  res.send(result);
})
```

For example your document like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58454926668bde730a460e15"),
    "notification" : [ 
        {
            "notification_id" : ObjectId("58454926668bde730a460e16"),
            "isRead" : true
        }, 
        {
            "notification_id" : ObjectId("58454926668bde730a460e17"),
            "isRead" : true
        }, 
        {
            "notification_id" : ObjectId("58454926668bde730a460e19"),
            "isRead" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

then out put will be like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58454926668bde730a460e15"),
    "notification" : [ 
        {
            "notification_id" : ObjectId("58454926668bde730a460e19"),
            "isReady" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

If you want to get all notifications if any one of `isRead` is `false` then your query is correct just check `userid` is is exist in DB that you passed and some notification `isRead` is false . Also can use `$elemMatch`

```
Model.User.find({
   _id: userid
   "notification":{ $elemMatch: { "isRead": false} }
}).exec(function (err, result) {
  console.log(result);
  res.send(result);
})
```

Comment: I don't understand why negative and can you tell me ?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your reference is wrong because the query is correct.

Make sure you are referring what you exporting.

Example:

If you are referring `notifications` in your schema code then you should export the same name in code.

```
module.exports = mongoose.model("notifications", userNotificationSchema);
```

Take a look at here https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/mongoose-referencing-schema-in-properties-and-arrays/